# Why did Sean get onto the plane in the Event?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-event

In the first episode of the great but short-lived NBC TV series "The Event", Sean Walker is shown getting on a plane that is being flown to Coral Gables, Florida to assassinate the President. The plane is being piloted by Sean's girlfriend's father Michael Buchanan, who is being forced to participate in this assassination attempt because his family is being held hostage. Sean is shown trying to get into the cockpit and stop Michael from crashing the plane.

But my question is, why did Sean get onto the plane? As far as I can tell, chronologically the last time we saw Sean before thist was in a flashback where he had found out that his girlfriend Leila Buchanan was missing in her hotel room. He asked the front desk where she was, and the hotel had no record of Sean or Leila, the cruise they were traveling on had no record of them either, and Leila's phone number had been disconnected. Hotel security tried to apprehend him, because they thought he had snuck onto the cruise or something, but he ran away before they could catch him.

But what happened between that scene and him being on the plane? They say (in a later episode) that he used a false ID as a flight crewman or something to get on the plane, but what was his motivation for doing this, how did he know the flight was being used for an assassination attempt, and how did he know that his girlfriend's father was piloting it? How did he go from looking for his girlfriend to trying to save his girlfriend's father and/or prevent presidential assassinations? And then afterwards, of course, he goes back to looking for his girlfriend, so the whole going on the plane part seems out of place.

Can anyone shed light on this?

Answer (score 4):

From what I recall when watching the show, they packed of lot of things into the pilot episode and this is never actually answered in the season.

That being the case I think the simple answer is probably the correct one. From the Event wiki:

> How did Sean Walker learn that Michael Buchanan was going to pilot the plane and to crash the plane into the President's residence?
>
> →PROBABLY: Someone working with Simon Lee approached Sean in Antigua after he fled the cruise ship.
>
> [The Event Wiki](http://theevent.wikia.com/wiki/I_Haven't_Told_You_Everything/Theories)

In the "Theory" section of the same wiki it was explained this way:

> Meanwhile, there's another side-story where this guy's fiancee is kidnapped. Some mysterious people contact him telling him he has to hijack a plane and fly it into the President's mansion before he can make the announcement. The guy refuses, but then realizes these people also contacted his fiancee's father and gave him the same ultimatum. Her father happens to be a pilot so the dude boards the plane in an attempt to stop him.

Obviously this is not concrete, but it is really the only explanation that makes any sense when one was not provided by the shows producers.

Comment: This explanation doesn't make sense to me, because if an associate of Thomas contacted Sean and told him about the plane, why is it that after the plane landed in the desert, Sean only tried to find Vicki Roberts?  Why wouldn't he also try to find Thomas' associate, since that person clearly knew something about Leila's disappearance?

Comment: Since it's all speculation, I can only add that it's possible that he felt he had a hotter trail with Vicki, since he he knew what she looked like and where she had been. But like I said it's pure speculation.